# Gridview's (populated by SqlDataSource) Update is not updating, don't know how to trace

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm still a newbie in ASP.NET, and right now, my Gridview is not "updating" when I hit "Update". Here is how I have my GridView w/ the SqlDataSource :

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProjectTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataSourceID="PopulateProjectTable" DataKeyNames="ProjectID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectID" HeaderText="Project ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProjectID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectDescription" HeaderText="Project Description" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProjectDescription" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectNotes" HeaderText="Project Notes" SortExpression="ProjectNotes" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PopulateProjectTable" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sandboxConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Projects]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Projects] SET ProjectNotes = @project_notes">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="project_notes" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have no code in the code behind. When I hit "Edit", the third column is suppose to be "editable". When I hit "Update", the page does a postback but what was entered in the third column does not persist and is instead lost. What is going on?

In addition, how would I trace this issue? This is so in the future, I can see what the SQL string is. Thank you.

EDIT: Turns out to be a typo that caused my issue. Problem solved!

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem but your `Update` statement is missing a `WHERE` clause.  `WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectID`

Comment: Where's your code behind for your button?

Comment: @RickS, just added in the `WHERE` and the parameter, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @ragerory, there is no "button". And like I said, there is no code behind.

Comment: @Leon sorry I did not see that part. Is the spelling correct on the `ProjectNotes` DataField? The problem you are describing sounds like the field is not bound properly.

Comment: @ragerory, that was it. It was a spelling mistake. I have no idea how I made that mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the spelling correct on the ProjectNotes DataField? The problem you are describing sounds like the field is not bound properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would run SQL profiler while hitting the update.  To see what exactly was being sent back to the Database.

You should see your parameter as well.  Set the filter to the DB your looking at if you have multiple and give it a try and realtime run the same test by hitting the update button again.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your update command  from this

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Projects] SET ProjectNotes = @project_notes"
```

to this

```
 UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Projects] SET ProjectNotes = @project_notes" WHERE ProjectID=@ProjectID
```

Comment: You mean just like my comment 23 minutes ago?  And they said it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, @Rick absolutely right - there is no way update will work without where

Comment: Yeah, I added that in. Did not work, I will update my code in just a moment to reflect two changes I made.

Answer (score 0):

Please add to your DataSource

```
 OnUpdated="OnDSUpdatedHandler">
```

and add the following method

```
  <script runat="server">
 private void OnDSUpdatedHandler(Object source, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) {

   var dbg = e;
     }
   </script>
```

Set breakpoint on line

```
var dbg = e;
```

and examine what is being in that variable. The answer should be there